# Can you remove /pagetwo from a multipage website?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

If you a have a multipage website for example www.examplesite.com 
and you have a few pages : www.examplesite.com/pagetwo etc...

is it possible to remove the /pagetwo from the searchbar? or present this in a cooler way. I suppose www.examplesite.com/2 is more minimal, but is there any way to completely remove this?

Many Thanks 
Harry

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the state of the URL via JS like this:

`history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");`

Read more here: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

In the variation above, the last bit (`"/"`) says push the URL back to site root.

But I'd recommend asking why you want to do this and if it's the best solution. You could easily create bad user experiences and prevent people from bookmarking or sharing the content they intend to.

Comment: Thanks. 
Perhaps to keep the site domain looking clean. 
Perhaps if you buy an expensive domain like:  

circle.com 

you don't want the user to see: 

circle.com/page-two/harry-dry

I didn't think of the bookmarking issues though. 
Thanks for raising that